# How to track browser version through piwik?

Tags: browser, matomo

I am a developer and I am trying to collect data to determine what browsers we need to support for our website. We have piwik installed and tracking for several months.  But I notice that it does not seem to keep track of which version of IE a visitor is using.

Is there a way to get Piwik to track the browser and version and make it visible in a report?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a way already in visitor>>setting tab. Just click "Related report: Browser version"

[image]